# How can I practice speaking English by myself?

Tags: english, speaking, conversation

Currently I'm learning by myself with videos but mostly with textbooks. I have no much people to speak with and I'm trying to find some ways to practice conversation. Do someone have any hint?!

Comment: [I don't have many people to talk to...] :)

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience—I'm now on my fourth language—the best way to learn a spoken language is to think in that language.

Let me clarify my point: If a person who only speaks English desires to drink water, they think "I want to drink water." So, they "think" what they wish to do in English words. The language of the thought changes depending on their native language, of course, but the meaning will be retained. So, if you force yourself to think in a non-native language, it will become easier to speak it.

Essentially, rather than going through the thought process of "I want to drink water," in Portuguese (or whichever language you may speak), try your best to think the same sentence in English. It will be difficult at first and you'll definitely be clueless what to think because of limited vocabulary at times, but after a while, it'll feel like a conversation with yourself.

**Note:** If you are one of the few people who cannot think in words, but rather see images in their mind, then I suggest you simply find a mirror and have a conversation with your reflection by speaking out loud.

Comment: Beginners and intermediates can rarely "think in the L2".

Comment: @Lambie What about starting with very simple sentences, e.g. in French "quelle heure est-il?" or "nous sommes le combien?"  That's probably a question that everyone asks and answers to himself at least once a day, and a beginner can learn how to ask it and to answer it in French (or another language) with minimal vocabulary.

Answer (score -1):

Before the world became "all digital", **there were language labs**.

Language labs are a way to listen to real speech, and then repeat what you hear.

Also, they have **graded exercises** (increasingly difficult) that leave blanks where you answer and then can listen to your answers and their answers.

This is really the best way to learn because of the way the exercises become more and more difficult as you move through the course.

Here is just one just place to do this:

[English language lab](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/educator-english/english-language-lab-activities/)

You can search for others but this is *the best method*, if you don't have a real tutor or teacher.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try this. I discovered I was using aspects of this method instinctively. [[The Indiana Jones Method For Learning Foreign Languages]](https://gainweightjournal.com/the-indiana-jones-method-for-learning-foreign-languages/). At this link you will find Heinrich Schliemann's method of learning.

Answer (score -2):

You can use sites like Tandem to talk to native speakers, or you can read articles and books in the language you want to learn and then correct your pronunciation with Google Translate.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! I noticed that you've recently posted several answers. Some of those really look like one-line comments, failing to address questions (or are only tangentially relative). Please note that **every** answer on this site must address the original Q and stand on its own on addressing it (e.g. not be a commentary to the Q or to another A). Also, while your personal experience is valuable, we prefer answers that are **based on facts and references, preferably on academic research**. Your experience/opinion can be part of it, but can't be the whole basis of your post.